# How to publish builds to Artifactory from GitLab CI?

Tags: artifactory, artifacts, gitlab-ci

I am looking for an easy and clean way to publish artefacts build with GitLab CI onto Artifactory.

I was able to spot https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus/blob/af8af9552966348a15dc1bf488efb29a8ca27111/lib/omnibus/publishers/artifactory_publisher.rb but I wasnt able to find any documentation regarding how I am supposed to configure it to make it work.

Note: I am looking for a gitlab_ci.yaml approach, not as in implementing it externally.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Answer (score 12):

At a basic level, this can be done with the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) tools. Unless you want to embed configuration in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` (I don't) you will first need to run (on your runner):

```
jfrog rt c
```

This will prompt for your Artifactory URL and an API key by default. After entering these items, you'll find `~/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf` containing JSON like so:

```
    {
      "artifactory": {
        "url": "http://artifactory.localdomain:8081/artifactory/",
        "apiKey": "AKCp2V77EgrbwK8NB8z3LdvCkeBPq2axeF3MeVK1GFYhbeN5cfaWf8xJXLKkuqTCs5obpzxzu"
      }
    }
```

You can copy this file to the GitLab runner's home directory - in my case, `/home/gitlab-runner/.jfrog/jfrog-cli.conf`

Once that is done, the runner will authenticate with Artifactory using that configuration. There are a bunch of other possibilities for authentication if you don't want to use API keys - check the JFrog CLI docs.

Before moving on, make sure the 'jfrog' executable is in a known location, with execute permissions for the gitlab-runner user. From here you can call the utility within your `.gitlab-ci.yml` - here is a minimal example for a `node.js` app that will pass the Git tag as the artifact version:

```
stages:
  - build-package
build-package:
  stage: build-package
  script:
    - npm install
    - tar -czf test-project.tar.gz *
    - /usr/local/bin/jfrog rt u --build-name="Test Project" --build-number="${CI_BUILD_TAG}" test-project.tar.gz test-repo
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're building with maven this is how I managed to do mine:

**Note**: you need to have your artifactory credentials (user and pass) ready.

1. Create a master password and generate an encrypted password from it. The procedure on how to create a masterpassword can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)
2. In your pipeline settings in gitlab, create 2 secret variables, one for the username and the other for your encrypted password.
3. Update or create a `settings.xml` file in `.m2` directory for maven builds. Your `settings.xml` should look like this:

   ```
   <settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <servers>
       <server>
         <id>central</id>
         <username>${env.ARTIFACTORY_USER}</username>
         <password>${env.ENCRYPTED_PASS}</password>
       </server>
     </servers>
   </settings>
   ```
4. In your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, you need to use this `settings.xml` like this:

   ```
   image: maven:latest

   variables:
     MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
     MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

   cache:
     paths:
       - .m2/repository/
       - target/

   build:
     stage: build
     script:
       - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
   ```

and that's it. This should work. You can visit [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/articles/artifactory_and_gitlab/) for more about how to use artifactory with maven

Comment: Am trying to follow your solution, first of all, how do I create an artifacotry credential can you point me to a site? I keep seeing jfrog and it isn't free.

Comment: @alexdavies you need jfrog cli which is free https://jfrog.com/getcli/ if you want to create your artifactory credentials for gitlab-ci. Please follow the steps here under the `Example` section https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory, you'll have an idea of creating your artifactory credentials for your gitlab-ci.

Comment: yea thanks, I already figured that out and got it working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I got to this question from a related search, so I thought it might be relevant to others too:

I ended up using an `mvn deploy` job that was bound to the `deploy` stage for gitlab.

Here is the relevant job portion:

```
deploy:jdk8:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS deploy site site:stage'
  only:
    - master
  # Archive up the built documentation site.
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/staging
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
```

Answer (score 0):

JFrog [documentation](https://jfrog.com/blog/gitlab-and-artifactory-on-your-mark-get-set-build/) suggests this:

```
image: gradle:latest
 
before_script:
 # Download JFrog CLI
 -  curl -fL https://install-cli.jfrog.io | sh
 # configure artifactory server
 - jf config add $JFROG_PLATFORM_SERVER_ID--url=$JFROG_PLATFORM_URL --user=$JFROG_PLATFORM_USER --password=$JFROG_PLATFORM_PASS
 - jf config show
 
 # configure gradle, set upload and download repos
 - jf gradlec --repo-resolve $JFROG_PLATFORM_REPO --repo-deploy $JFROG_PLATFORM_REPO
 
gitlab-ci-gradle-build: #This job name will be used as the build info repository name in artifactory
 stage: build
 script:
   # upload the built artifact to artifactory
   - jf gradle clean artifactoryPublish --build-name=$CI_JOB_NAME --build-number=$CI_JOB_ID
   # Collect environment variables for the build
   - jf rt bce $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
   # Collect VCS details from git and add them to the build
   - jf rt bag $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
   # Publish build info
   - jf rt bp $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
   # Scan with xray
   - jf bs $CI_JOB_NAME $CI_JOB_ID
```

The variables `JFROG_*` need to be defined in the CI/CD section of the Gitlab repository.

If this is gonna be shared among a set of projects, I would bake a container image with JFrog defaults and leave only the API Key to be set per project.