# Artifactory build integration with Gitlab

Tags: maven, gitlab, artifactory

A beginner to both gitlab and artifactory. I am looking forward to integrating build artifacts in gitlab to jfrog artifactory. 
have a gitlab runner that triggers the build based on the script in .yaml file. how to proceed further?
Found a similar question here. But not a very clear answer. 
[How to publish builds to Artifactory from GitLab CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442613/how-to-publish-builds-to-artifactory-from-gitlab-ci)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contacted Jfrog Artifactory FAQ team and mailed me below link which has the partial integration with gitlab

For Maven : https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/articles/artifactory_and_gitlab/